Periodic chrome page rerender clears all canvases. Is this documented behaviour, and if so how can I prevent it?
Periodically, chrome will rerender the entire page. This is perhaps because it runs out of memory for the tab? My App uses a lot of memory. The screen appears to entirely blank, and then the DOM returns, as if the page was refreshed. However, canvases that had previously been painted do not rerender, instead just clearing.
These canvases are painted using canvas.getContext("2d").
Is this documented behaviour? Can I detect it and then repaint myself? Can I prevent it?

If I were you, I'd concentrate on fixing the Periodically, chrome will rerender the entire page issue

This sounds not correct. There are probably errors in the code. It's Impossible to say without seeing the code, obviously.
